# how to extract a specific text with no tag by python scrapy?（new problem）

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to extract target text in html like this below:

[image]

my scrapy code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
class MmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'name'
    start_urls = ['file:///Users/saihhold/Desktop/maimai.mht']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//div[@class="media-body"]/div/div[1]'):
            yield {
                title.xpath('.//text()').getall()
            }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(MmSpider)
    process.start()
```

then use this command to run it:

```
scrapy runspider mmspider.py -o mm.jl
```

but mm.jl file is empty, is there any problem with my code or xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is okey but xpath selection was incorrect.You can follow the next example how to grab title using xpath.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
class MmSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'name'
    start_urls = ['https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//h3[@class="_h3_cuogz_1"]'):
            yield {
                'title':title.xpath('.//text()').getall()[-1].replace('\xa0','')
            }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(MmSpider)
    process.start()
```

Output:

```
{'title': '2001: A Space Odyssey (1968)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'The Godfather (1972)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'Citizen Kane (1941)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'Jeanne Dielman, 23, Quai du Commerce, 1080 Bruxelles (1975)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'La Dolce Vita (1960)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'Seven Samurai (1954)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'In the Mood for Love (2000)'}
2022-04-12 15:17:36 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.timeout.com/film/best-movies-of-all-time>
{'title': 'There Will Be Blood (2007)'}
```

... so on

Comment: Hi, it's uesful, thanks ,but when i  used your code to run it on another website, the problem showed up again. I edited the question, please see it.

Comment: @Saihhold Chiu file:///Users/saihhold/Desktop/maimai.mht isn't  a correct start_urls

Comment: Because it’s a local mht file, same  as a web page.

Comment: Scrapy didn't feed this type of file and element selection from website to website aren't the same level of  html tree

Comment: Do you know any method to extract data from local html file?

Comment: Actually,I can't  say nothing at this moment. It would be better to create new question on that topic. Thanks